# How do I test the method that converts a Java object list to XML and writes in a file?

Tags: java, xml, unit-testing

I have a method that converts `HotelData` object List to `XML` and writes in file. Say,

```
@Override
public void dataToXmlConverter() {

  /* 1. the method inherited the list `List<HotelData> rows`, 
  so, it doesn't take any arguments as parameter to the method */     



 DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = null;

    try {
        docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
    Element rootElement = doc.createElement("info");
    doc.appendChild(rootElement);

  /* 2. convert the List to the XML format */  
   for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {

       // some conversation code 
   }


 /*3. write the XML to the file */ 
  try{
     // write to the XML file 
  }

  catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("CONVERTED TO XML");
}
```

I have some experience with unit testing, but, my issue is what should I test here, specially when no argument is taken and also the return type is `void`. Please, advise. Some sample code will be helpful.

Comment: When it has no Parameter, where do the data to convert from?

Comment: Wha I would do is giving the class a `Writer` object as constructor parameter and replace it in Test with a `StringWriter`. Alo I'd pass the Data as Parameter. Then I could verify that the `StringWriter`s content is the expected XML.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many things to test here.

A few can be:

1. You can test a message for a successful write.
2. You can write something particular and then read the file to find if the same message is written.

Comment: How do I use the List<HotelData> as the method doesn't take any argument ? For `1` I have a message `"CONVERTED TO XML"` and I can check that. The `2` will be little hard I believe. Can you provide some sample code to getting started ?

Comment: You can read this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm